Android emulator starting failed: Invalid physicalDevice
I got an error: vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties: Invalid physicalDevice [VUID-vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties-physicalDevice-parameter]
This is the detail of the avd:
avd detail
This is what I tried:
emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_30 -verbose

This is the output:
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath D:\programData\AndroidSDK\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\lxt\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -skin pixel_3a
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -skindir D:\programData\AndroidSDK\skins\
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
VERBOSE | querying file version info API...
VERBOSE | found kernelbase.dll
VERBOSE | GetFileVersionInfoSizeW found. On Windows 10?
VERBOSE | GetFileVersionInfoW found. On Windows 10?
VERBOSE | VerQueryValueW found. Can query file versions
VERBOSE | queryFileVersionInfo: path not found: amdvlk64.dll
VERBOSE | querying file version info API...
VERBOSE | queryFileVersionInfo: path not found: amdvlk32.dll
VERBOSE | querying file version info API...
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -kernel D:\programData\AndroidSDK\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64
VERBOSE | Target arch = 'x86'
VERBOSE | Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
VERBOSE | Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
VERBOSE | Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -ramdisk D:\programData\AndroidSDK\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\\ramdisk.img
VERBOSE | Using initial system image: D:\programData\AndroidSDK\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\\system.img
VERBOSE | Using initial vendor image: D:\programData\AndroidSDK\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\\vendor.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -data C:\Android\.android\avd\Pixel_3a_API_30.avd\userdata-qemu.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -initdata C:\Android\.android\avd\Pixel_3a_API_30.avd\userdata.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -cache C:\Android\.android\avd\Pixel_3a_API_30.avd\cache.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -sdcard C:\Android\.android\avd\Pixel_3a_API_30.avd\sdcard.img
VERBOSE | Physical RAM size: 2048MB
VERBOSE | VM heap size 256MB is below hardware specified minimum of 512MB,setting it to that value
VERBOSE | System image is read only
INFO    | IPv4 server found: 10.128.1.114
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: 806:8697:102::6995:80:0
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: 806:8697:102::6995:80:0
 (2x)
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: f810:8697:102::6995:80:0
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: f810:8697:102::6995:80:0
 (2x)
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: 2019:8697:102::6995:80:0
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: 2019:8697:102::6995:80:0
 (2x)
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: 101f:8697:102::6995:80:0
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: 101f:8697:102::6995:80:0
 (2x)
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: b025:8697:102::6995:80:0
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: b025:8697:102::6995:80:0
 (2x)
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: 102e:8697:102::6995:80:0
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: 102e:8697:102::6995:80:0
 (2x)
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: d841:8697:102::6995:80:0
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: d841:8697:102::6995:80:0
 (2x)
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: d847:8697:102::6995:80:0
VERBOSE | Ignore IPv6 address: d847:8697:102::6995:80:0
 (2x)
VERBOSE | Found 1 DNS servers:
VERBOSE |       10.128.1.114
VERBOSE | trying to load skin file 'D:\programData\AndroidSDK\skins\\pixel_3a\layout'
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Android\.android\avd\Pixel_3a_API_30.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
VERBOSE | CPU Acceleration: working
VERBOSE | CPU Acceleration status: GVM (version 2.1) is installed and usable.
VERBOSE | handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
VERBOSE | registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.cmdline' = 'androidboot.logcat=*:V androidboot.consolepipe=qemu_pipe,pipe:logcat'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.logcat' = 'start'
INFO    | Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
VERBOSE | GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
VERBOSE | Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
VERBOSE | create display 0
VERBOSE | setDisplayPose 0 x 0 y 0 w 1080 h 2220 dpi 0
INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll
ERROR:             vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties: Invalid physicalDevice [VUID-vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties-physicalDevice-parameter]

I'm expecting to start an avd normally. If I run from the android studio, it simply gets stuck and no error message.

I have solved this issue, just add -feature -Vulkan in the command.
emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_30 -verbose -feature -Vulkan


I had the same issue while starting emulator from Android studio. The problem is that Vulkan doesn`t work. If you have nVidia videocard with Amd iGPU this might help you
https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5182/~/unable-to-launch-vulkan-apps%2Fgame-on-notebooks-with-amd-radeon-igpus

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
